# trying to add this formula in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, calculation

So I'm building a discord level bot and am trying to get this formula to be into my code, but idk how I would do that.

This is the formula `5 * (lvl ^ 2) + (50 * lvl) + 100 - xp`

when pasting in this `console.log(5 * (78 ^ 2) + (50 * 78) + 100)`
it gives me an answer that is 4380, when the result should be 34420.

Comment: Use `**` instead of `^` The latter is a binary XOR operator

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I didn't think it was such a simple fix xD